# keeping sites looking the same in IE, Chrome and Firefox

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Can anyone tell me the best way to ensure asp.net sites look the same when view in IE, Chrome or Firefox?

I've just finished one which in testing seems fine in IE but not the other 2.

I have not used CSS on this site as its not that big, I just formatted the masterpage as I wanted it.

Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually code for Firefox first.  That makes things match almost 100% in Chrome, Safari and IE9 usually.  Then I go through and test in IE 8 and 7.  Minor adjustments are typically made within the same CSS file.  For example, IE7 usually needs to have dimensions of a container explicitly set, where most modern day browsers don't require it and render things properly.

In those rare cases that you do need to style something specifically for one or more versions of IE, use conditional comments.  Here are some good links on conditional comments and how to target specific browsers and versions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will need to use CSS to get this to look similar in all browsers. I say similar as it is unlikely you will ever get it looking exactly the same.

Basically you will need to use the conditional CSS tags http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks.shtml

I would recommend spliting out the style to the a CSS and getting that working in Chrome and Firefox. Then use the tutorial linked and add in IE hacks to make it look better.

Comment: reading the tutorial it makes sense, think this would work if its only really the masterpage layout thats skewed? ie the title banner and menu buttons?  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way of making a site look the same in all the browsers. As **caveman_dick** said, maybe it's even impossible. You have to use CSS and sometimes javascript...
But to help you, you can use some programs that simulate different browsers engines, so that you could see how your site behaves. Just google **browser simulator**. :)